# Downgrade Samsung Galaxy Tab from Android v3.1 to v2.3.3 Gingerbread

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread, galaxy-tab, samsung-mobile

I am new developer of Android's tablet, if I buy a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1-inch with Android 3.1 installed, can I downgrade it back to version 2.3.3 Gingerbread??
Since I want to test my apps running on v2.3.3

Any possible problems for doing this?

Comment: This is not the best page to ask that question. First, you can use the emulator to test in 2.3.3 device (the emulator works fine) Second, i think this is a better page to ask your question http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, I don't know there is an Android's stack exchange. Also, my app must be tested on real device.

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible, if you can find a ROM built for the 10.1 Tab which is running 2.3.3

I would advise you check out [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) and see what ROMs that have available. You will need to wipe your device though, so backup any data you may have on it. Also, you will need to Root your device, which will be explain on the XDA forums.

Comment: I don't know much about Android's device, does ROOT mean JAILBREAK? Also, do I have to find a ROM dedicated for Galaxy Tab 10.1? Any other 2.3.3's ROMs won't work, right?? Thanks.

Comment: From that comment, I would advise you dont even get started on downgrading. Its not a simple process, and requires time and patience. Using the Android Emulator is your best option to prevent any damage you may do to your device, including bricking it. For reference, JAIBREAK and ROOT are similar, but not the same.

Comment: My app must be tested on real device. I did jailbreak before, does ROOT much more complicated?? Thanks.